# Is it possible to check file type even before it's selected?

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I know that after a file is selected, then we can check the file type.
But I am wondering if it's possible to check the file during the select window, so user will not even be able to select a bad file format.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to check file type but you can restrict them by using accept attribute, as it will show only listed format files in select dialog box

```
<!-- (IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, Firefox 42+) -->
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```